# How to automate a keystroke using Win32 and Ruby?

Tags: ruby, events, automation

I wonder if anyone knows how to use Win32 to automate a keystroke using Ruby?

Comment: You want to pass a keystroke to the System? isn't that kind of invasive? like pressing Alt+F4 multiple times closing everything.

Comment: i know how to automate a click and wonder how to do that for a keystroke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend checking out Ian Dees' [Scripted GUI Testing With Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356182).  This example of sending keystrokes to a Windows program comes from the book's 2nd chapter.  The supporting script is [available here](http://bitbucket.org/undees/idgtr-code/src/tip/early_success/windows_basics.rb).

```
# START:typing
"this is some text".upcase.each_byte do |b| #<callout id="co.upcase"/>
  keybd_event.call b, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0
  sleep 0.05
  keybd_event.call b, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
  sleep 0.05
end
# END:typing
```

I highly-recommend this book for anyone doing platform-specific, or cross-platform GUI automation and testing.